# useSelector not rerending when dispatch used from other compoent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I have a large component so I want to split it in multiple components.

The problem is, the child component not rerending when parent emit disptach.
That only works when dipsatch and selector are in the same component.

The dispatch and selector concern the same store and the dispatch update correctly selector value.

I put the first example working fine.

```
const Champ: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const champErrorMessage = useAppSelector(selectChampErrorMessage);
  const endingDuration = useAppSelector(selectEndingDuration);
  const champ = useAppSelector(selectChamp);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch<any>(getFarmPlotConfig()).then(() =>
      dispatch<any>(getChampAsyncThunk(new Date().toString())),
    );
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch<any>(getChampAsyncThunk(new Date().toString()));
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  });

  return (
    <Card>
      <CardHeader>
        <h5>Champs de récolte</h5>
      </CardHeader>
      <CardBody>
        <div className="d-flex bd-highlight">
          <div className="flex-grow-1 card-text">
            <CardInfo>
              <CardInfoRow>
                <CardInfoItem title="Disponible">
                  {champ?.champsItems?.length} / {champ?.disponible}
                </CardInfoItem>
                <CardInfoItem title="Temps restant">
                  {endingDuration} seconde
                </CardInfoItem>
              </CardInfoRow>
            </CardInfo>
            <div>{champErrorMessage}&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
              Recolter
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <ChampBody></ChampBody>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

And the other with split component ChampInfo not rerending when parent emit dispatch.

```
const Champ: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch<any>(getFarmPlotConfig()).then(() =>
      dispatch<any>(getChampAsyncThunk(new Date().toString())),
    );
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch<any>(getChampAsyncThunk(new Date().toString()));
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  });

  return (
    <Card>
      <CardHeader>
        <h5>Champs de récolte</h5>
      </CardHeader>
      <CardBody>
        <ChampInfo></ChampInfo>
        <ChampBody></ChampBody>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  );
};

function ChampInfo() {
  const champErrorMessage = useAppSelector(selectChampErrorMessage);
  const endingDuration = useAppSelector(selectEndingDuration);
  const champ = useAppSelector(selectChamp);
  return (
    <div className="d-flex bd-highlight">
      <div className="flex-grow-1 card-text">
        <CardInfo>
          <CardInfoRow>
            <CardInfoItem title="Disponible">
              {champ?.champsItems?.length} / {champ?.disponible}
            </CardInfoItem>
            <CardInfoItem title="Temps restant">
              {endingDuration} seconde
            </CardInfoItem>
          </CardInfoRow>
        </CardInfo>
        <div>{champErrorMessage}&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
          Recolter
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```